# How to start cycle by using push button

Tags: marlin

Can any one help me out that how to start a cycle by just using a push button.

Note: Using Marlin firmware, Arduino Mega, Ramps 1.4

I haven't tried altering the Marlin code (as I am new to coding), I was just thinking of adopting this feature as it will be very easy for CNC DIY maker using Marlin code to run a cycle in a loop.

Comment: Way more information required. What have you tired so far and what didn't work? Schematic, code? This is way to broad currently.

Comment: HI and welcome to SE.3DP btw! :-)

Comment: What is a "cycle"? I have no clue what you mean, please explain so we can help you out! Cheers, and welcome!

Comment: Yes, @0scar raises a good point, what *cycle*, or rather a cycle of what? A print cycle, a batch cycle? I seems like you have a good idea in mind, but it's not all that clear or well explained. Please edit and update your answer. Thanks... :-)

Comment: @Greenonline, actually in terms of CNC cycle start is very descriptive.

Comment: @user77232 - OK, but for the non-CNC initiated crowd, I think a brief explanation *might* be useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/7713/how-to-make-physical-buttons-send-gcode

Answer (score 1):

Unless you know the structure of the Marlin firmware pretty well, are good at coding (in C/C++), and are familiar with programming microcontrollers, then I wouldn't attempt to do this, IMHO. Adding new features can cause a number of issues elsewhere in the code and need rigourous planning and testing as well as discussion with the Marlin community.

You *could* however make a request (i.e. raise an issue) to the [Marlin community on Github](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Marlin), however, I would seriously suggest posting to the [Marlin forum](https://reprap.org/forum/list.php?415), on RepRap, first, as random suggestions and issues raised on Github aren't really appreciated, without checking on the forum first...

If you really want to get into coding, then I would suggest buying an Arduino Uno and some components and messing about with those first, as well as visiting our excellent [Arduino Q&A site on StackExchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com) as well as the [Arduino forums](https://forum.arduino.cc).

Answer (score 1):

Don't go modifying Marlin to do this unless you're using a 32 bit µC.

You're better off controlling Marlin with [OctoPrint](https://community.octoprint.org) and writing/finding a module that allows you to kick off a print when a key is pressed on a connected keyboard or pendant.